# How to use structs in binary search?

Tags: c, struct, binary-search

I'm trying to learn c (its my first language) and i have some problems with this task. (It is no homework!)

Task:

Implement the binary search  algorithm on an array of structs of the following kind (sorry for my English).

```
    struct {
    unsigned int number;
    char* food;
    int price; 
} pk;
```

- The given array is sorted in ascending order
- When the searched number is found, give `<nr>: <food> <price>\n` back
- When the searched number isn't found, give `<nr> is not in pk \n` back  and return -1

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct {
    unsigned int number;
    char* food;
    int price; 
} pk;


int binary search(int pk[], int l, int r, unsigned int number){
    int center;
    int start = l;
    int end = r;

    if (start == end){
        if (pk[start] == number){
            printf ("%d is in pk\n", number);   // do not know how to use the struct 
        }else{
            printf ("%d is not in pk\n", number);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        center = (start + end)/2;
        if (number <= pk[center]){
            return binary search(pk, start, center, number);
        }else{
            return binary search(pk, center+1, end, number);
        }
    }
}
```

My questions:
1) Could this code work?
2) How I can use this struct to fulfill the task, in my opinion I should to it complete different then now.

Comment: You don't pass any of your structs to the search function. Take another look at `int pk[]` -- I don't think you meant to pass an array of `int`s here, did you?

Comment: That's true, because i din't know how to use the struct in this case

Answer (score 1):

Enable all compiler warnings!

When `if (start == end){ if (pk[start] == number){` is true, code returns *nothing*.

I'd expect `return start;` in this case.

---

Avoid `start + end` overflow

```
// center = (start + end)/2;
center = start + (end - start)/2;
```

---

Slightly different:
I'd recommend to return a pointer to the array on success and `NULL` on failure

```
// int binary search(pk a[], int l, int r, unsigned int number){
pk *binary search(pk a[], int l, int r, unsigned int number){
    int start = l;
    int end = r;

    if (start == end){
        if (a[start].number == number){
            printf ("%d is in a[] at index\n", number, start);
            return &a[start];
        }else{
            printf ("%d is not in a[]\n", number);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        int center = start + (end - start)/2;
        if (number <= a[center].number){
            return binary search(a, start, center, number);
        }else{
            return binary search(a, center+1, end, number);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Advanced: Better code would use `size_t` for indexing and a `const a[]`

```
pk *binary search(const pk a[], size_t l, size_t r, unsigned int number){
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
What does a[start].number do? I think the point "." is a reference to the struct, but but a[start] "." number is strange

Comment: @Marie.L `a[start]` indexes the array `a[]`.  `a[start].number` references the member `.number` from that array element.

Comment: But why we want a reference at this point. And how does a[start].number work.
Let be a[] = {1,2,3} , start = 2 and number = 3. 
Then we have a[2] = 3 == 3 = number  but  a[2].number  makes what? Sry for those maybe trivial questions, but its hart for me to unterstand

Comment: @Marie.L `a` in the answer is a `pk a[]`, same as a `pk *a`.  It is a pointer to a `pk`, not an `int`.  "Let be `a[] = {1,2,3}`" is unclear as that appearers to be initializing an array of `int`.  `a[start]` is not a reference.  Sorry not more helpful.